# How to install SketchUp2017 on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, playonlinux

There is a new SketchUp version out, 2017. I tried to install it through PlayOnLinux, but it says 'You must use Win7 SP1 or higher'.

If I set via `winecfg` to Win8, wine tries to install .net4.5.2 but it never ends.

Then I installed .net4.5.2 via winetricks, like this, after installing wine-staging
https://github.com/wine-compholio/wine-staging/wiki/Installation#-ubuntulinux-mint
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33102

Then I set Windows8 via winecfg and got a message

[image]

If I try wine64 SketchUpPro I get `.wine' is a 32-bit installation, it cannot support 64-bit applications.`

On their website you can find:
https://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36208

> Compatibility Changes SketchUp 2017 With the release of SketchUp 2017,
>   we've removed support for 32-bit operating systems, OpenGL 2.0, and
>   software rendering of models (as opposed to hardware acceleration). We
>   also removed support for OS X 10.9 (Mavericks.)

Is it possible to install 64-bit apps via wine and how to do it with SketchUpPro? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my experience a good fix for that is to type 

`mkdir ~/.wine64
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine64 SketchUpPro`

or rather than specifying that variable in the command, type 
`export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64`
before running wine

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Sketchup/comments/epmm7o/installing_sketchup_make_2017_on_linux_mint/) finally allowed me to run SketchUp 2017 on Ubuntu/Linux Mint.

It isn't required, but I like to use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) in order to manage my wine installs.

- Install PlayOnLinux (I used 4.3.4)
- Create a new virtual drive
- Install wine 4 (64 bit)
- Configure wine

  - select "Windows 7" as system
    [image]
  - add "riched20" as library
    [image]
- Install `dotnet452_beta_test` as component
  [image]
- PlayOnLinux is stubborn, and tells me DotNet 4.5.2 will not work with "Windows 7", so it sets the system to "Windows 2003".
- Sketchup 2017 requires "Windows 7", so I set the system back to "Windows 7" in wine config.
- I finally install Sketchup Make 2017 64 bit (from https://help.sketchup.com/en/downloading-older-versions)
- SketchUp complains that 2017 is not getting any younger. Well yes, but it's also the last free desktop version.
- It works perfectly, and it's even smoother than on my Windows computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**2022 answer for Ubuntu Impish 21.10**

1: Install staging version of Wine

```
apt-add-repository -y 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/' 
curl https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/winehq.gpg --import
chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
apt update
apt install --install-recommends wine-staging winehq-staging wine-binfmt
```

2: Install prerequisites for Sketchup 2017 Make and launch the installer. (IIRC you need to ignore installer complaint about Mono.)

```
apt install winetricks mesa-utils winbind cabextract mono-complete
export WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.sketchup2017
export WINEARCH=win64
wineboot
winetricks win7 dotnet48 vcrun2019 corefonts
wine64 Downloads/sketchupmake-2017-2-2555-90782-en-x64.exe
```

3: Create desktop entry file (`~/Desktop/sketchup.desktop`) for Sketchup. Replace the correct home directory path in WINEPREFIX.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SketchUp 2017
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/user/.sketchup2017" WINEARCH=win64 wine64 C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\\\SketchUp\\\\SketchUp\\ 2017\\\\SketchUp.exe
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=D962_SketchUpIcon.0
StartupWMClass=sketchup.exe
```

Enjoy.

I didn't get the solid inspector plugin to work properly but at least it allows you to cycle through the problem spots with Shift-Tab.